# How to apply function over subset of columns in data.table while grouping by some other column?

Tags: r, data.table

As an example take this data.table:

```
foo <- data.table(id = letters[1:5], group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), x=1:5, y = (-4):0, z = 2:6)

   id group x  y z
1:  a     a 1 -4 2
2:  b     a 2 -3 3
3:  c     a 3 -2 4
4:  d     b 4 -1 5
5:  e     b 5  0 6
```

I want to normalize the column vectors x, y, and z (`x/sum(x)`) by groups, i.e. by those groups defined by column `group`. I also want to preserve all other remaining columns.

I am trying something along these lines:

```
foo[, lapply(.SD[, -1], function(x) {x/sum(x)}), by = group]

   group         x         y         z
1:     a 0.1666667 0.4444444 0.2222222
2:     a 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
3:     a 0.5000000 0.2222222 0.4444444
4:     b 0.4444444 1.0000000 0.4545455
5:     b 0.5555556 0.0000000 0.5454545
```

but column `id` is dropped because of `.SD[, -1]`, however I do not know how to apply over the numeric columns only without dropping it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could specify the `.SDcols` and assign the output back to the same columns.

```
foo[, names(foo)[3:5]  := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/sum(x)),
                 by = group, .SDcols = x:z]
```

Note that the type should be the same for the output and the input.  If the input is `integer` and output is `numeric` it would have problem.  So, change the `class` to `numeric` first and then do the assignment

```
nm1 <- names(foo)[3:5]
#or programmatically based on checking whether column is numeric
#nm1 <- foo[, which(unlist(lapply(.SD, is.numeric)))]
foo[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = nm1
      ][, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/sum(x)), 
                by = group, .SDcols = nm1][]
```

A `tidyverse` approach to the above would be

```
library(dplyr)
foo %>% 
     group_by(group) %>%
     mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(./sum(.)))
```